# How to create a dll just like this with a change of text?

Tags: c#, c, assembly, dll, reverse-engineering

I have added the link to the dll.

I want to create the same kind of dll but with a change inside the file containing 
"O:\76\d3c7d16586ecd8fdc7c8781a.pdf" - I want to change this link inside the dll.

Can someone give me a full source code to make this kind of dll ?

Its around 2 KB in filesize.

http://www.datafilehost.com/d/589b215c
Uncheck "Use our download manager and get recommended downloads" before downloading the file.

Comment: Try "Resource hacker" tool yourself.

Comment: Is this a DLL you wrote previously?  Is it in C#?

Comment: I am not sure if its written in C#

Comment: Resource hacker shows nothing.

Comment: Try Telerik's JustDecompile.  If it's written in C# and not signed, you can get the source code and do whatever you like.

Comment: Okay I will try , isn't for .NET ??

Comment: It is saying not supported file.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a big block of text (the size of the maximum URL you expect to use) into the globals and then later open the dll, insert the string, and save a copy. I apologize for not putting code here, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I am confused , I do not know to do so.